# Eclipse text highlights

Tags: java, eclipse, editor, syntax-highlighting

In eclipse when I'm pressing 'ctrl' (no matter what next) part of my code turns red with a yellow background.
What is this and how to disable it?

Also when this happens 'ctrl' + 'space' stop working until I restart eclipse.

here what it looks like this:

[image]

**EDIT:**

How to reproduce: start the auto completion (ctrl + space) on something you already wrote:

class.fun

step after the `.` and  start the auto complition

now each time I hold ctrl, `fun` glows yellow:

class.**fun**

Comment: A shot in the dark: looks like a rogue plugin to me. Can you please post the list of the installed plugins? Another thing that may help to pin point the problem is key bindings. Check out Window->Preferences->General->Keys and search by Ctrl

Comment: n00b response : install a fresh new eclipse,reinstall your plugins and let this new install points to your existing workspace(s) :p

Comment: that is what I did.. new computer, new eclipse no plugins

Comment: @vitaly where do I find the installed plugins?

Comment: Help->Install New Software...->What is already installed?->Plug-ins

Comment: Also, what eclipse [flavor](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) are you using? Classic?

Comment: yes classic, in the installed software there is only eclipse SDK and all it contains (very long list of plugins)

Comment: so did u manage to solve i have the same problem exacly

Comment: No I didn't find the solution yet.

Comment: I have the exact same problem (under Eclipse ADT in fact) and still no solution. At least this is not the Hyperlinking as mentioned below.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know how to disable it but one thing which you can try out is select all by processing Ctrl+A and then cutting it by pressing Ctrl+X and then again pasting it back.Check out!

Answer (score 2):

Might be `on demand hyperlink navigation` acting up.

Do you also see the text become underlined as you hover over it?

Try this:

```
Window->Preferences->General->Editors->Text Editors->Hyperlinking
[v] Enable on demand hyperlink style navigation
Default modifier key: [Ctrl]
```

Turn it off and `Apply` the change.

See if it makes a difference.

If it is not that, perhaps you find the culprit elsewhere in your preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would help but have you tried: Windows->Preferences->Java->Editor->MarkOccurrences and unchecking it?  Doesn't seem to fit exactly but may help you discover the problem.

Comment: Marked occurences look different, but lucky enogh this helped me solve my problem with marked occurences

Answer (score 0):

Go to Preferences -> General -> Basic -> Hyperlink Text Color

You can change it in order not to see color changes with ctrl key.

Comment: I don't have basic in general.

Answer (score 0):

The yellow and red effect is a second mode of the Content Assist feature that is activated by pressing ctrl while in the middle of auto-completing something. Preferences->Java->Editor->Content Assist. Top of the window.
Also see Preferences->Java->Editor for the matching completion overwrite colors.